# How to debug Solr test cases in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, solr, junit

When I try to run a Solr test case from Eclipse (Right-Click > Run As > JUnit Test), I get the following printed to the Eclipse console:

```
Feb 27, 2012 5:21:06 PM org.apache.solr.SolrTestCaseJ4 deleteCore
INFO: ###deleteCore
```

The whole process runs and exits very quickly without running the actual test case.

I have tried to set my working directory according to the instructions at  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TestingSolr to no avail.  Those instructions refer to a directory that doesn't actually exist any more (src/test/test-files), so I tried setting it to solr/core/src/test-files without any luck.  I'm using the latest SOLR trunk (as of Feb 27,2012)

What am I missing?

Comment: What is you test case? can you post the code?

Comment: I'm trying to run org.apache.solr.TestDistributedSearch.  It's a large class that inherits from a base LuceneTestCase class and is run by a LuceneTestCaseRunner.  The particular test case I run doesn't matter, as I get the same behavior for all solr test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your own answer looks like you're adding to the classpath a jar which contains the code which should already be in your workspace, thus in your classpath.
The Solr build file has a really handy eclipse target which generates the eclipse project, so you can import it in one click. Just run `ant eclipse` from the root directory and you shouldn't have problems with classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't noticed it before, but the test case was throwing an exception saying

```
A SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec with name 'Lucene40' does not exist. You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.The current classpath supports the following names: []
```

I solved the problem by adding lucene/build/core/lucene-core-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to the classpath in the test case's Run Configuration.  It feels like I shouldn't have to do this, but I don't have time to investigate further.

If anyone else can tell me how to remove this dependency, I'll attribute the answer to you.

I also had to set the working directory in my Run Configuration to solr/core/src/test-files

Comment: Did you run the `ant eclipse` command first? I mean, you're adding to the classpath a jar which contains the code which should already be in your workspace, thus in your classpath.

Comment: I wasn't aware there was an `ant eclipse` target.  That did the trick!  I had set up the project by hand before.

Comment: Great, I'm adding my comment as answer.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911393/error-simple-example-lucene-4-0-with-source-not-jar-lib